# Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1 Xcode Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

Really don't know how to fix this issue. Whenever the game starts up it crashes and gives me this output. I took a look at a few other articles on this issue but they didn't help.

The error happens on the 'let enemyBall' line I commented where the issue is appearing

```
@objc func spawnEnem() {

        let enemyBall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "enemyBall") #Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1 issue HERE


        self.addChild(enemyBall)
        enemyBall.size = CGSize(width: 25.0, height: 25.0)
        enemyBall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: enemyBall.size.width/2)
        enemyBall.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true


        // Physics of our enemy
        enemyBall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: enemyBall.size.width / 2)
        enemyBall.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagroy.EnemyHere // setting enemyBall to our physics
        enemyBall.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagroy.smallBall | PhysicsCatagroy.mainBall // if our enemy ball hits the small ball or main ball run this
        enemyBall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagroy.smallBall | PhysicsCatagroy.mainBall // allows enemy Ball to collide with these small ball and main ball
        enemyBall.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false // we dont want enemy effected by gravity
        enemyBall.name = "Enemy"

    switch randomPosNum {

        case 0:
            enemyBall.position.x = 0

            let posY = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(frame.size.height))
            enemyBall.position.y = CGFloat(posY)
            break
        case 1:
            enemyBall.position.y = 0

            let posX = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(frame.size.width))
            enemyBall.position.x = CGFloat(posX)
            break
        case 2:
            enemyBall.position.y = frame.size.height

            let posX = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(frame.size.width))
            enemyBall.position.x = CGFloat(posX)
            break
        case 3:
            enemyBall.position.x = frame.size.width

            let posY = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(frame.size.height))
            enemyBall.position.y = CGFloat(posY)

            break
        default:


            break
        }
               enemyBall.run(SKAction.move(to: mainBall.position, duration: 3)) // moves enemy ball to the player ball



    }
```

Comment: You have an active breakpoint, remove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a breakpoint active:

```
Press CMD + 8
```

to see active breakpoints, click on anything that appears on the left and click the delete button, it should look like this:

[image]

then try running it again.

Breakpoints are a way to debug code, it's basically a thing that stops your code at a specific point to see what's been executed, in what order, and what variables have what data assigned to them.

Comment: It wants me to delete the actual let statement that creates the Enemy Node

Comment: put a screenshot in your question for me